# Gradle plugin 2.0.0-alpha9 failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'

Tags: android

After Update Android Studio to Android Studio Preview 9 and Gradle to Gradle::2.0.0-alpha9 ...

I Got Error :

> failed to find target with hash string 'android-23'

I have change gradle to 2.0.0-alpha8 , but my app still cannot run, its always show configuration like this :
[image]

So ho to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue in preview 9 of android studio 2.0 preview version.

avoid using

```
2.0.0-alpha9 //gradle plugin
```

use this instead.

```
2.0.0-beta2
```

in your project gradle file.

I have checked this with preview 9 and beta 2 works perfectly.

And bye the way forget about preview 9 android studio 2.0 preview beta 2 (don't download beta 1, it had a blocker bug) is available now on [canary channel](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/latest)